# KDiff3 as temporary git diff tool

Tags: git, kdiff3

I would like to use KDiff3 as Git diff tool, without losing the default text based diff tool. That is I don't want to alter the default functionality of the `git diff` command.

Could you suggest a command line for this?

Example:

```
$ git diff
... the git diff as usual...

$ kdiff3 <?some params?>
... the kdiff3 guis shows up reporting the diffs (even one file at the time is fine)...
```

Comment: Actually yes, using `git difftool` i can use meld as visual diff tool on each modified file